# Resetting Xbox 360 hard drive to default settings

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I have recently used a transfer cable with an Xbox 360 hard drive in order to connect it to my Xbox to allow for more storage. Now I have removed the configuration of the hard drive to be used for additional storage, but when I place it in the correct Xbox hard drive location it is not recognised, can I maybe have help resetting the hard drive to default in order for it to be recognised by the Xbox?

Comment: Are you talking about the vanilla Xbox 360 (Premium/Elite), or about Trinity (Xbox 360 S)?

Comment: it is an elite xbox and the harddrive is custom i think because it has a clear case. this should not affect this tho because it was working before i used it for additional storage on my other xbox via a transfer cable.

Comment: i should also mention that the xbox has not had recent updates due to it not being used for a while and i cannot update it because it requires memory and the harddrive is not recognised. if required to resolve this i can use a memory stick for a temporary memory for the update to take place.

Comment: I did a google search on your question, but did not manage to turn up with anything meaningful. The only question that seemed relevant to your problem was buried on the 3rd page and did not have any answers in it. This question is definitely not an easy one to answer. Sorry I couldn't be of any help :(

Comment: thankyou for attempting nolan it is much appreciated. just hope i can resolve it soon.

Comment: Do you have any other USB devices (memory stick or otherwise) plugged into the Xbox?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way (or a very difficulty way) to get your xbox 360 hdd back to stock settings. The xbox360 hdd slot only reads drives with an specific pertition and since you change the settings (I guess to ntfs or fat32) your xbox doesn't want to read it anymore. 
You could try to search for a program that reformat your hdd so your xbox 360 recognizes it again. You could also try to connect the hdd trough a usb port.

So, yes you have to reset / format it